# format property in class to return phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to format what I have below to return a phone number?

```
private string _Phone;
    [DataMember]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse(_Phone)); }
        set { _Phone = value; }
    }
```

Comment: What does _Phone look like now and format do you want the output to look like? (888) 555-5555? 888-555-5555? etc

Comment: right now _Phone is just 0000000000 ... would like it to be (000) 000-0000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use String.Format if you convert the string to a long first.

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse("8005551212"))
```

Comment: so how would i modify what i posted?

Comment: Just return the value from the String.Format above.
I would test first whether or not the string is null or whitespace before doing it, and if it is, pass back your default value above.

Comment: is what I have correct? If not, would you mind showing me how this is done?

Comment: That should do what you want.  Like I said, just make sure that you have a value that will parse properly.  Otherwise you'll end up with a weird string coming out of that format.  You could test the String.Length and anything less than 10 would return a default of some sort, etc... But you've got the general idea.